# How can I use a variable from a function with ngClass?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Using Angular 4, I'm trying to use ngClass by comparing a variable, `sender` created in a function and an object from an array, `item.sender`.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of items" [ngClass]="{'me': item.sender == sender, 'notme': item.sender != sender}">
  <ion-card-header>
    @{{item.sender}}
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    {{item.message}}
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

The function with the variable `sender` is:

```
send(desc: string) {
  console.log("message:", desc);

  var listkey = this.listKey;
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var uid = user.uid;
  var email = user.email;
  var sender = email.substring(0, email.lastIndexOf("@"));

  var messagecontent = {
    message: this.messagecontent,
    sender: sender,
  };

  firebase.database().ref('userlists' + '/' + listkey +  '/' + 'chat').push(messagecontent);
  this.messagecontent = '';
}
```

Can this by done, and if so, what am I missing?

Comment: `sender` should be declared as a public class member, not as a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public  sender:string = '';


   send(desc: string) {
     console.log("message:", desc);
    ... 
      this.sender = email.substring(0, email.lastIndexOf("@"));
    ....
```

You also better replacing all your `var`s with `let`s and `const`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary equation and apply for the `ngClass`

**CODE**

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of items" [ngClass]="item.sender === sender ? me : notme">
  <ion-card-header>
    @{{item.sender}}
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    {{item.message}}
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```